# Apt doesn't want to install an already installed package

Tags: apt, package-management

I wanted to download autopsy for my Ubuntu version 22.04.2, I installed a .deb file for Sleuthkit-java, version 4.12.0 prior to this which worked fine. After this I first had a zip file from the autopsy Github, which I tried installing, but I wasn't sure I was doing it right. I found that I could also download autopsy from apt, so I deleted the zip and folder I had from autopsy and did `sudo apt install autopsy`

This was the output from the install  :

[image: Output install]

So apt seems to not recognize the file libtsk19 I think? Using 'apt list' still shows it in the system:

```
apt list libtsk19
Listing... Done
libtsk19/jammy 4.11.1+dfsg-1 amd64
```

So I'm not really sure what I'm doing wrong, I can't `apt upgrade` anymore and reinstalling the programs doesn't do much.

Trying to run autopsy starts and immediately stops the program because it 'Cant open log: autopsy.log at /usr/share/autopsy/lib/Print.pm line 383'

I'm unsure what I have done wrong and how I can fix this. I hope you can provide me with a solution.

Comment: Please [edit your question](https://askubuntu.com/posts/1467665/edit) to include the complete output (copy/paste please) of `sudo apt update` and of `apt policy libtsk19`